# FancyArrowPatch get the precise position of the endpoint while using NetworkX

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I'm trying to replicate this picture using NetworkX and matplotlib
[image: enter code here]

I created the network a no problem here

```py
graph = nx.Graph()
elist = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 2)]
graph.add_edges_from(elist)
pos = {0: (-1, 2), 1: (2, 2), 2: (3, 0.5), 3: (2, -1.5), 4: (-1.5, -1), 5: (0, 0)}
```

Now in order to create the point I wanted to first plot the nodes with draw_networkx_nodes and then the edges separately and manipulate the matplotlib objects. The idea is to scatter some points getting the endpoints from the networkx edges positions. The problem is on the edges where I use the routing with `FancyArrowPatch`.

**When using this method `FancyArrowPatch.get_path()` doesn't give the precise position of the endpoints.**
Why is this the case? Ist there a way to get the precise position of the endpoints.

Below is the code and the result I got.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=200)
ax.set_axis_off()

node_object = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(graph, pos=pos, node_size=3000, node_color="#d3d3d3")
edge_object = nx.draw_networkx_edges(
    graph,
    pos=pos,
    node_size=10000,
    edge_color="#808080",
    width=2,
    arrows=True
)

node_object.set_zorder(-1)
for el in edge_object:
    paths = el.get_path().vertices[0], el.get_path().vertices[2]
    x, y = np.transpose(paths)
    middle = (paths[0] + paths[1]) / 2
    dist = np.abs(paths[1] - paths[0])
    
    print(middle, dist)
    print(el, x, y, fig.dpi)


    ax.scatter(x, y, s=100, c="#3a649d", edgecolors="#808080", linewidths=2)
```

[image]

Comment: The node size argument in `draw_networkx_edges` is used to shrink the edges so that the matplotlib edge artists do not overlap the node artists. If you want the edges to touch your (large) node artists, then you need to match the node size arguments in `draw_networkx_nodes` and `draw_networkx_edges`. if you want the edges to extend into the middle of the nodes, call `draw_networkx_edges` with `node_size=0`.

Comment: Personally, I would use matplotlib directly for a bespoke plot like this. The networkx drawing functions are just very thin wrappers around matplotlib's `Line2D` and `scatter` anyway, and if you want to make any changes to their output, it usually ends up being more work than using matplotlib directly.

Comment: Yes! at the end I made it myself using matplotlib directly.
I used some simple geometry using a parameter to manually stretch the length of the edges, and then plotting the end points as a `ax.scatter`.
I will publish it soon as an answer because I'm super busy right now.